# Install Windows 10 theme in Ubuntu

Tags: unity, software-installation, themes

I want to make my Ubuntu look like Windows 10, so I have downloaded the [Windows 10 Transformation Pack Light theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Windows+10+Theme?content=171327) from gnome-look.org, but I don't know how to install or apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing your Windows 10 theme, install `unity-tweak-tool` to apply it:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Now open Unity Tweak Tool and go to  *Appearance* → *Theme* option and choose your *Windows 10* theme.

[image: Unity Tweak Tool theme selection interface]

Answer (score 2):

> This method gets the source code from the master branch, thus always installing the latest version.
>
> If you have earlier downloaded the pack, make sure it is from the below mentioned site.

1. Get the TransPack installer [from here](https://github.com/B00merang-Project/TransPack/archive/master.zip) (GitHub repo).
2. Unpack the package and open a terminal in the extracted folder. Add execution rights with:

   ```
   chmod +x install.sh
   ```
3. In the same terminal, run:

   ```
   ./install.sh
   ```
4. Choose which variant to install and wait till the process finishes.  *You may need to restart your system after the install*.
5. If the installation fails, open an issue, clearly explaining the error and including the log file if possible.

**To uninstall the package**

1. Open a terminal and navigate to where `uninstall.sh` is located.
2. Add execution rights with:

   ```
   chmod +x uninstall.sh
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   ./uninstall.sh
   ```