# Windows 10 explorer for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, themes, filemanager

I want to make Ubuntu look like windows 10, but I feel something missing without Ribbon UI file explorer.

Comment: Why not uninstall Ubuntu and install Windows 10? That looks exactly like Windows 10. Or run Windows 10 in a virtual machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Windows 10 theme in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886874/install-windows-10-theme-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try ZorinOS or Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Try ubuntu mate or kubuntu, althouth kubuntu feels more like windows. And there is more graphical enviroments.
But first you need to install synaptic to install another enviroment

Comment: most Ubuntu file explorer are feels too simplistic for me, I like the tool that presented on windows 10 ribbon and I use it alot than using keyboard shortcut or right click

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Windows-style functionality, using Ubuntu, or more generally speaking, the GNOME desktop environment, is the wrong approach. By design and by design decision of the GNOME desktop developers, the desktop itself and a lot of programs being part of GNOME, including the default file explorer [Files](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Files) (formerly known as Nautilus), are simplistic.

The usage of ribbon controller style menus is not common at all for most Linux-based programs.

There are some file explorers with more features for Linux. Kubuntu using the KDE desktop environment and Dolphin as the file explorer was already mentioned. There are also some programs emulating the look and feel of the classic Norton Commander, e.g. [Double Commander](https://github.com/doublecmd/doublecmd) [GNOME Commander](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-commander/) or [Krusader](https://invent.kde.org/utilities/krusader). Plus there are some really powerfull file managers for the terminal like [Ranger](https://ranger.github.io/) or [Broot](https://dystroy.org/broot/). Which of course follow a total different philosophy regarding the UI than graphical programs.